# iPhone Cocos2D - converting a float to GLubyte

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have a UISlider giving me float values between 0 and 255 and I need to set the opacity of an Cocos2D that is in Glubyte.

How do I convert a float to GLubyte ??????

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `GLubyte` is simply defined as:

```
typedef unsigned char  GLubyte;
```

So, conversion is actually no problem (have a look at [this post](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html), which offers a few possible approaches behind the "basic" `(int)(x+0.5)`), except for "out-of-range" values (since an unsigned char can represent decimal between 0 and 255). In short, you should decide what to do with floating point values that cannot be represented as unsigned integers.

Since you say that your slider gives you values between 0 and 255, you should have no problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
static_cast<GLubyte>(floatNumber * 255.f);
```

I didnt notice the UISlider range is already between 0-255.. so remove the multiply above answer..

```
static_cast<GLubyte>(floatNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your slider is already configured for the range 0-255, then you don't have to scale the value, you just have to convert the type. Something like this should work:

```
GLubyte component = (GLubyte)lroundf(slider.value);
```